# JQuery UI Drag and Swap two divs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop, swap

Trying to drag and drop (swap) two divs (containing couple of child divs).

Here is my jsfiddle attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/VhB4n/3/

Seems like the child divs that I expect to be dragged together (since drag enabled on parent div) can be dragged and dropped independently. Is is possible to drag and drop both header and 
body divs (Hdr1 & Body1) together and swap with the other Hdr2 and Body2 divs?

Thanks.

Code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CurveDiv</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>


        .cTracks {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: 10px;
            width: 500px;
            height:700px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        .sTrack {
            float: left;
            width: 212px;
            height: 700px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        .sTrackHdr {
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 212px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
        }
        .sTrackBody {
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 212px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( ".sTrack" ).sortable();

            $( ".sTrack" ).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="curveTracks" class="cTracks">
        <div id="singleTrack" class="sTrack">
            <div id="singleTrackHdr" class="sTrackHdr">
                Header1
            </div>
            <div id="singleTrackBody" class="sTrackBody">
                Body1
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="singleTrack1" class="sTrack">
            <div id="singleTrackHdr1" class="sTrackHdr">
                Header2
            </div>
            <div id="singleTrackBody1" class="sTrackBody">
                Body2
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ or http://johnny.github.com/jquery-sortable/

Comment: Both look pretty good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap header and body together. All you need to do is wrap the header and body with a extra div.

In this case you code looks like:

```
<body>
    <div id="curveTracks" class="cTracks">
        <div id="singleTrack" class="sTrack">
            <div>
                 <div id="singleTrackHdr" class="sTrackHdr">
                     Header1
                 </div>
                 <div id="singleTrackBody" class="sTrackBody">
                     Body1
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="singleTrack1" class="sTrack">
            <div>
                <div id="singleTrackHdr1" class="sTrackHdr">
                    Header2
                </div>
                <div id="singleTrackBody1" class="sTrackBody">
                    Body2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Nothing to change for the javascript code.

NOTE: This is the case when you move header and body together not separately.

Comment: aah...Got it. Thanks. Though messes up the left alignment of the tracks - but I think I might be able to reset that.